# what does find-debuginfo.sh in rpmbuild do? how can I get rid of it?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I have two boxes that I'm using to build a source rpm. One of them runs:

```
/usr/lib/rpm/find-debuginfo.sh /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/name-of-package
```

which adds three `name.debug` files to the RPM_BUID_ROOT.

the other build box does not run find-debuginfo.sh and does not generate these files.

- What does `find-debuginfo.sh` do?
- what causes it to run?
- how can I make it not run?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use rpm macro magic to disable building of the debug package (place this somewhere in the spec file):

```
%define  debug_package %{nil}
```

I don't know why one of your boxes builds it and the other does not.

Comment: likely different versions of rpm on these boxes.

Answer (score 7):

find-debuginfo.sh separates the dwarf debuginfo from main binaries/libraries into separate files, which can be packaged into separate FOO-debuginfo subrpms.  That way, a user not interested in debugging doesn't have to install the -debuginfo and thus save disk space.